# Convert this custom string format into DateTime?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

How to convert the following string

```
    09/11/2011 9:40:55 pm
    20/11/2011 3:40:55 am
```

into C# DateTime ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

```
string dateString = "20/11/2011 3:40:55 am";
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
   dateString,
   "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score -1):

DateTime.Parse:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

See also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

For example:

```
string dateString = "5/1/2008 8:30:52 AM";
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(dateString, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That will parse as May 1st, not January 5th.

Comment: The example is cut/pasted directly from MSDN (from the above link).  And yes, it is parsed in MM/DD/YYYY format by default (i.e. May 1, 2008).  Similarly, the OP's example "09/11/2011 9:40:55 pm" will, by default, be Sep 11, 2011.

Comment: But given the second example, it's clearly *meant* to be parsed as dd/MM/yyyy, as there aren't 20 months in the year. That's why bobbymcr's example specifies the format explicitly.

Comment: Wouldn't the solution would be to provide the culture for the string?  You could also parse it exactly if you are guarantee to have the same format every single time.

Answer (score -2):

```
DateTime DT_1 = new DateTime(2011, 11, 9, 21, 40, 55);
DateTime DT_2 = new DateTime(2011, 11, 20, 15, 40, 55);
```

Comment: That's not performing a conversion from a string though, which is the point of the question.

Comment: The question asks about parsing a string.